# The line rotate with unexpected scaling

Tags: manim

The scene is simple, one Line and rotate PI/2 with below code:

```
ln = Line(ORIGIN, RIGHT*2)
self.add(ln)
self.wait()
self.play(ApplyMethod(ln.rotate, PI/2, OUT))
```

However, during the rotating, seemingly scaling at the same time, I check the axis is [0 0 1] that is z axis, I suppose the length of the line should be kept unchanged.

How to prevent the line from scaling? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Rotate` or `Rotating`, see [this](https://manim-tb-manual.000webhostapp.com/tree/animations/movement.html#rotating).

```py
class RotateVector(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        coord_start=[1,1,0]
        coord_end=[2,3,0]
        dot_start=Dot().move_to(coord_start)
        dot_end=Dot().move_to(coord_end)
        vector=Arrow(coord_start,coord_end,buff=0)
        vector.set_color(RED)

        self.add(dot_start,dot_end)
        self.play(GrowArrow(vector))

        self.play(
            Rotating(
                        vector,
                        radians=PI*2,
                        about_point=coord_start,
                        rate_func=smooth,
                        run_time=1
                    )
        )
        self.wait()
        self.play(
            Rotating(
                        vector,
                        radians=PI*2,
                        about_point=coord_end,
                        rate_func=linear,
                        run_time=1
                    )
        )
        self.wait()
```

---

## Edits

You can create a custom animation:

```py
class RotatingAndMove(Animation):
    CONFIG = {
        "axis": OUT,
        "radians": TAU,
        "run_time": 5,
        "rate_func": linear,
        "about_point": None,
        "about_edge": None,
    }
    def __init__(self, mobject, direction,**kwargs):
        assert(isinstance(mobject, Mobject))
        digest_config(self, kwargs)
        self.mobject = mobject
        self.direction = direction

    def interpolate_mobject(self, alpha):
        self.mobject.become(self.starting_mobject)
        self.mobject.rotate(
            alpha * self.radians,
            axis=self.axis,
            about_point=self.about_point,
            about_edge=self.about_edge,
        )
        self.mobject.shift(alpha*self.direction)

class NewSceneRotate(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        arrow=Vector(UP)
        arrow.to_corner(UL)
        self.play(GrowArrow(arrow))
        self.play(
                RotatingAndMove(arrow,RIGHT*12+DOWN*4)
            )
        self.wait()
```

Or you can use `UpdateFromAlphaFunc`:

```py
class NewSceneRotateUpdate(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        arrow=Vector(UP)
        arrow.to_corner(UL)

        direction=RIGHT*12+DOWN*4
        radians=TAU
        arrow.starting_mobject=arrow.copy()

        def update_arrow(mob,alpha):
            mob.become(mob.starting_mobject)
            mob.rotate(alpha*radians)
            mob.shift(alpha*direction)

        self.play(GrowArrow(arrow))
        self.play(
                UpdateFromAlphaFunc(arrow,update_arrow,rate_func=linear,run_time=5)
            )
        self.wait()
```

Something that should be very clear is that when you define an update function, it is not the same to use **dt** as **alpha**. That is, it is not the same to define

```py
        def update_function(mob,dt)
```

as

```py
        def update_function(mob,alpha)
```

**dt** varies with the fps of the video, and is calculated as follows:

```py
dt = 1/self.camera.frame_rate
# You don't have to calculate it, manim already does it by default,
# I just write it so you know where it comes from.
```

Where `self` refers to the `Scene` class.
And **alpha** varies from 0 to 1, in fact, you can write the previus scene with this update method and get the same result:

```py
        def update_arrow(mob,dt):
            alpha=interpolate(0,1,dt)
            mob.become(mob.starting_mobject)
            mob.rotate(alpha*radians)
            mob.shift(alpha*direction)
```

This can be useful if you want alpha to vary in different intervals, use

```
            alpha=interpolate(alpha_start,alpha_end,dt)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but what if rotating and move_to at the same time? Rotate and Rotating are both Transform.

Comment: No, Rotating is not a subclass of Transform, Rotate is. If you want to rotate and move at the same time then it would be advisable to use an update function, I already passed you the examples of how the update functions are used. Using the update functions you can control the rotation and the distance traveled. Or in case you want to apply it on multiple objects you can create your own animation.. See [this](https://pastebin.com/TUZzSfyb).

Comment: This code must be outdated, the custom animation no longer works as is.